# incorrect position of the value in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using crystal reports 11. I have placed a database fields some where in the report designer. But when printing, the value for that field is printed somewhere else. Lock position and size, keep together isnt working. what could be the reason behind this?

Comment: What do you mean it 'is printed somewhere else'?

Comment: A screenshot, perhaps?